# Rank of a variable in a counter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data stored in a counter e.g.

```
industries = Counter({'Automotive': 17, 'Commercial Banks': 10, 'Insurance': 4, 'Hospitals': 2, 'Other': 2})
```

I am interested in looking up the 'index' (i.e. 'rank') of a particular variable. For example, if I am interested in `Automotive` to return that it has the highest key, `commercial banks` has the second highest.

At the moment I am converting to a list, and then looking up the index of that item. e.g.

```
industries_list = [key[0] for key in industries.most_common()]
rank_of_automotive = industries_list.index("Automotive")
```

Is there a way of doing this directly form the counter without the need to convert to a list?

[Obviously, I am aware that my current code does not deal with variables of the same value correctly - i.e. although `Hospitals` and `Other` which both have value 2, my could would return a different rank for them. This isn't a big issue for me, but if it were the case that both returned the same value that would also be find]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`most_common` will get you a sorted list of the most common values.

```
>>> industries.most_common()
[('Automotive', 17),
 ('Commercial Banks', 10),
 ('Insurance', 4),
 ('Hospitals', 2),
 ('Other', 2)]
```

You can use this to create a dictionary mapping each industry to its rank:

```
ranking = {pair[0]: rank 
           for rank, pair in enumerate(industries.most_common())}

>>> ranking
{'Automotive': 0,
 'Commercial Banks': 1,
 'Hospitals': 3,
 'Insurance': 2,
 'Other': 4}
```

Note that the order can be arbitrary if the values are tied (e.g. Hospitals and Other).

Comment: +1, I might recommend renaming `n, i` to `rank, pair` for readability. It'll reach 80 chars, but it's probably worth it? Might be a pedantic point

Comment: much better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a shorter approach:

```
mapping = dict((item[1][0], item[0]) for item in enumerate(industries.most_common()))
print(mapping["Automotive"])
```